# Android Back Navigation proper

Tags: android

I have made the one **Main_Activity** And made many **Fragment**.
For example I am open the First Fragment and  Second Fragment open from the first.My question is if i pressed the  back Button on device the application terminate.Can possible  i pressed the back Button the Screen Back second Fragment to First again pressed the screen move on Main_Activity then app terminate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly open fragments. They need to be inside some activity.
If you want to control the action of pressing the back button, you need to override the `onBackPressed()` method of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` to go back to previous fragment and override `onBackPress()` method if required.